# Constructing a Sequential Circuit with two D Flip Flops

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

A sequential circuit with two D flip flops (*A and B*), two inputs (*x and y*), and one output (*z*) is specified by the following next-state and output equations:

- *A(t+1) = xy' + xB*
- *B(t+1) = xA + xB'*
- *z = A*

I have drawn the logic diagram of the circuit, attached below, but I am having trouble with listing the corresponding state table. If there is a simpler way to come up with the table rather than tracing every wire, I would love to know how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Instead of tracing wires, you could use the next-state equations that you already have.

Comment: Another hint: What happens when `x` is 0?

Comment: @Dave Tweed All outputs from the AND and OR gates will be 0.

Comment: Exactly. `x` is the reset input to your state machine. Knowing that simplifies the analysis of the rest of it.

Answer (score 1):

In D flip flops input equations are same as the state equations, so what ever you get at the input of the D flip flop should be the output.

You can do this:

1.Write down all the possible input combinations for all the possible present states of the flip flop.

2.Then with the help of the equations available to you , you can find the value of the next state for each combination and this next state is your output and you can get the output. and hence your state table is complete with Present State , Inputs, Next State and output(Which in this case is the output of D flip flop).

P.S: Please tell if further clarification is needed anywhere.